# Error in Dependency property of type long

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, dependency-properties

I have an "Id" dependency property declared:

```
    public long Id
    {
        get { return (long)GetValue(IdProperty); }
        set { SetValue(IdProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty IdProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Id", typeof(long),
        typeof(Component), new PropertyMetadata(-1));
```

"Component" is a User Control that have "Id".

When I run the application it gives me an exeption:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.TypeInitializationException' occurred in PresentationCore.dll
>
> Additional information: The type initializer for 'My_Program.Component' threw an exception.

If i change the type "long" to "int" everything works fine.
What is the problem? can't I create a dependency property of type "long"?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try casting the default value to long:

```
new PropertyMetadata((long)-1);
```

Comment: Thank you very much it worked. I didn't know that the default type is considered int if not casted. Thanks a lot for your fast reply

Answer (score 4):

Try using suffix `L`, i.e.: `-1L`